# PostgreSQL full-text search from one column or two columns (A, AB but not B)?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of names with one column being given names and one column being surname.  Say I have the name "Mary Smith".  I want that row return when I search for "Smith" or "Mary Smith" but not for "Mary".  How can I achieve this for a full-text index?

Comment: So, if there are two names, search for either, but if only one, only search for surname. Because your title and explanation do not correspond logically.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
WHERE surname = 'yoursearch' OR (name || ' ' || surname) = 'yoursearch'
```

Both

```
WHERE surname = 'Smith' OR (name || ' ' || surname) = 'Smith'

WHERE surname = 'Mary Smith' OR (name || ' ' || surname) = 'Mary Smith'
```

returns Mary Smith but

```
WHERE surname = 'Mary' OR (name || ' ' || surname) = 'Mary'
```

does not

Comment: That's the correct logic, but I'd prefer to use full-text searching.

Comment: Do you really need full-text search? Full text search is for long text fields

Comment: I'd rather avoid ilike searches.

Comment: @BrunoCalza. Full-text search does not have to be for long text fields. It is actually done on tsvectors, which can be make up of one or many fields.

Comment: @JohnBarça you're right. it's just that i don't any benefit of using tsvectors on people's name. i don't know much about text search though